# google driveのスクリプトでエラーの原因が分からない

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Googleスプレッドシートで、特定のファイルを編集するたびに Script function not found: insertLastUpdated というエラーが出たという通知が来るのですが、そのファイルのスクリプトのどこにもinsertLastUpdatedという関数は使っていないため、原因が分からず困っています。
どなたか原因と解決法を分かりませんでしょうか。

通知の内容を以下に引用します。

> Your script, Untitled project, has recently failed to finish
>   successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure
>   the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving
>   future failure notifications, click here.
>
> The script is used by the document MySpredsheet.
>
> Summary: Error Message    Count Script function not found:
>   insertLastUpdated 183
>
> Details: Start    Function    Error Message   Trigger End 5/6/16 1:42
>   AM    insertLastUpdated   Script function not found:
>   insertLastUpdated edit    5/6/16 1:42 AM
>   (以下時間だけ違う同じエラーが並ぶ)

スクリプトの全文を以下に引用します。

```
var col_airshipname = 1;
var col_voyagerlength = 3;
var col_departdate = 4;
var col_returndate = 5;
var col_hull = 7;
var col_rigg = 8;
var col_fore = 9;
var col_aft = 10;
var col_sector = 12;
var col_itemname = 13;
var col_itemhq = 14;
var col_itemqty = 15;
var col_action = 17;

function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var currentCol = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var sheetname = sheet.getName();
  if(sheetname == "Schedule") {
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var data_airshipname = data[currentRow - 1][col_airshipname - 1];
    var data_voyagerlength = data[currentRow - 1][col_voyagerlength - 1];
    var data_departdate = data[currentRow - 1][col_departdate - 1];
    var data_returndate = data[currentRow - 1][col_returndate - 1];
    var data_hull = data[currentRow - 1][col_hull - 1];
    var data_rigg = data[currentRow - 1][col_rigg - 1];
    var data_fore = data[currentRow - 1][col_fore - 1];
    var data_aft = data[currentRow - 1][col_aft - 1];
    var data_sector = data[currentRow - 1][col_sector - 1];
    var data_itemname = data[currentRow - 1][col_itemname - 1];
    var data_itemhq = data[currentRow - 1][col_itemhq - 1];
    var data_itemqty = data[currentRow - 1][col_itemqty  - 1];
    var data_action = data[currentRow - 1][col_action - 1];
    if(currentRow > 1 && currentCol == col_action) {
      if(data_action == "◆") {
        sheet.getRange(currentRow, col_departdate).setValue(new Date());
        sheet.getRange(currentRow, col_action).setValue("");
      }
    } else if(currentRow > 1 && currentCol == col_itemqty) {
      if(data_itemqty != "") {
        var history_sheet = getHistorySheet();
        var new_row = 2;
        history_sheet.insertRowBefore(new_row);
        history_sheet.getRange(new_row, 1, 1, 15).setValues([[data_airshipname, "",  data_voyagerlength, data_departdate, data_returndate, "", data_hull, data_rigg, data_fore, data_aft, "", data_sector, data_itemname, data_itemhq, data_itemqty]]);
        sheet.getRange(currentRow, col_itemname, 1, 5).setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}

function getScheduleSheet() {
  if (getScheduleSheet.memoSheet) { return getScheduleSheet.memoSheet; }
  getScheduleSheet.memoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Schedule');
  return getScheduleSheet.memoSheet;
}
function getHistorySheet() {
  if (getHistorySheet.memoSheet) { return getHistorySheet.memoSheet; }
  getHistorySheet.memoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('History');
  return getHistorySheet.memoSheet;
}
```

Comment: スクリプトエディタのメニュー「リソース→すべてのトリガー」でinsertLastUpdatedが参照されていませんか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
「リソース→すべてのトリガー」にはonEditしか表示されていません。

どこか通常の操作で見えないところにあったりするのでしょうか？

Comment: トリガーは作成した人にしか見えないので、共有ファイル または 編集のためコピーしたファイルであれば、別の人が設置したままとなっているトリガーが残っているのかもしれません。